# Hash calculation in torrent clients

Tags: hash, bittorrent, torrent, magnet-uri

I was wondering if someone knows what a "hash" in a BitTorrent client is referring to, it is clearly not the `hash`code of the file, but something different.

I think thats more a magnet link to a file, but how is this connected to the file itself?

I just want to understand the construct behind the scene.
File <--> Hash <---> hash in torrent client

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `hash` in a torrent client or the `hash`you find in a `magnet-URI` is the SHA1-hash of the raw `bencoded` `info-dictionary`-part of a `torrent`-file.

To understand how that works you need to know two things:

- How a `torrent`-file is built.
- How `bencode`ing is done.

Both of these are explained in the offical bittorrent specification that you can find here: http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html

However I recommed that you instead read the inoffical specification that you can find here: https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification
as it is much easier to understand.

Comment: To get the real file from the torrent that has the hash value of the Info_hash.

Comment: To get the real file from the torrent that has the hash value of the Info_hash delete everything bevor "d5:files" and after "Æá67:privatei0ee".

9ee4:info|<-- Delete d5:filesld6:lengthi10 ...... // .... 67:privatei0ee Delete ->|22:rtorrent_meta_