# Python3 calculating torrent hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, torrent

Code below (apologies for ugliness), I'm running this to calculate the hash for a torrent but it is giving me a different answer than when I open that torrent directly in Transmission:

I'm testing on r_000 on this page: http://gen.lib.rus.ec/repository_torrent/

Transmission gives me: 63a04291a8b266d968aa7ab8a276543fa63a9e84

My code gives me: 1882ff6534ee4aa660e2fbf225c1796638bea4c0

```
import bencoding
from io import BytesIO
import binascii
import hashlib

with open("cache/r_000.torrent", "rb") as f:
    data = bencoding.bdecode(f.read())
info = data[b'info']
hashed_info = hashlib.sha1(info[b'pieces']).hexdigest()
print(hashed_info)
```

Any idea what I've screwed up? Thanks!

Comment: This has already been asked. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28162042/3151902).

Comment: Seems like you are hashing the `pieces`-value instead of the `info`-dictionary

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140766/hash-calculation-in-torrent-clients/28162042#28162042) first.
However, if you want to hash other files, I found this guide on Google:
[Hashing files with Python | Python Central](http://pythoncentral.io/hashing-files-with-python)

Comment: Yep , needed to take a step back and look again. Okay so the solution is to bencode the whole info dictionary and then hash that.

Comment: Bdecode and then Bencode may in some rare chases give the wrong info_hash. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749085/calculating-the-info-hash-of-a-torrent-file/19800109#19800109

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made the same mistake. Searching found this question and that helped me fix it. But to make it clearer for others who come this way via searches on how to do it from python3+ this is the explicit fix:

Change:

```
hashed_info = hashlib.sha1(info[b'pieces']).hexdigest()
```

to:

```
hashed_info = hashlib.sha1(bencoding.bencode(info)).hexdigest()
```

---

Thanks to [Encombe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3693974/encombe) for clarifying the info hash here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140766/28162042#28162042](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140766/hash-calculation-in-torrent-clients/28162042#28162042)

> The hash in a torrent client or the hash you find in a magnet-URI is
>   the SHA1-hash of the raw bencoded info-dictionary-part of a
>   torrent-file.

---

A full but minimalistic example is:

```
import bencoding, hashlib

objTorrentFile = open("r_0000.torrent", "rb")
decodedDict = bencoding.bdecode(objTorrentFile.read())

info_hash = hashlib.sha1(bencoding.bencode(decodedDict[b"info"])).hexdigest()
print(info_hash)
```

Result:

```
$ python3 example.py
63a04291a8b266d968aa7ab8a276543fa63a9e84
```

Comment: Good solution, but have in mind that in some rare cases, Bdecoding and then Bencoding before hashing, may give the [wrong info_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749085/calculating-the-info-hash-of-a-torrent-file/19800109#19800109).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. How would I prevent such an occurrence? Is it just when its in the wrong order and the decoder library sorts it that it will mismatch or is there other cases? The library I'm using is actually the [bencoder](https://github.com/utdemir/bencoder) library and I can see a part that sorts.